# How can I compare the value with the previous record, then modify the date field

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

```
CT|123456789|ABCDE|10202023|Deduction|30.00|
CT|123456789|ABCDE|10202023|Deduction|30.00| <--- change the date to 10062023
```

I want to compare the record to the previous one, if they are identical then I need to minus 14 days of the Date field. Can you please advise how can I do that in XSLT? Thanks.

Expected result:

```
CT|123456789|ABCDE|10202023|Deduction|30.00|
CT|123456789|ABCDE|10062023|Deduction|30.00|
```

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're able to parse the non-XML content, otherwise you would be asking about that. So if you have parsed it into an XML node tree, with ISO dates, you will have something like this:

```
<record a="CT" b="123456789" d="ABCDE"
     e="2023-10-20" f="Deduction" g="30.00"/>
```

and your requirement then translates into a template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="record[@e=preceding-sibling::record[1]/@e]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @e"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="e" select="xs:date(@e)-xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1D')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```